# Usage of "gleich" and "nur"

Tags: word-usage, difference, meaning-in-context

What is the difference between *gleich* and *nur*? Do they both mean *just*?

For example, consider the translation of "I am coming back in just 2 minutes".

> 1. Ich komme ***nur*** in 2 Minuten zurück.
> 2. Ich komme ***gleich*** in 2 Minuten zurück.

Comment: Your first example should be *Ich komme in nur 2 Minuten zurück* (different word order), emphasizing the short period of time before returning. In your second example "gleich" is not necessary, you should choose either a specific time ("in 2 Minuten") or "gleich" to indicate a short period of time.

Comment: I am tempted to copy @lejonet8's comment into the answer field ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Gleich* means *equal(ly)* and, in sense of time, *right away*

> Alle Menschen sind gleich. - All men are equal.
>
> Ich komme gleich. - I'll be right there.

*Nur* means *only*.

> Ich habe nur 3 Minuten Zeit. - I have only 3 minutes.

*Just* can mean *only* so sometimes it translates to *nur*. I wouldn't know of a case where *just* translates to *gleich*.

Answer (score 2):

When exiting a roundabout, my German satnav informs me "Gleich kommt die Ausfahrt", which seems to me to translate as 'the exit comes in a very short time', which pretty much confirms an earlier entry above.

Comment: "an earlier entry above"? Do you mean the answer of Emanuel?

Comment: Corrected: "die Ausfahrt" is a noun and therefore written capitalized in German.